# Grand Chess domain model and helper functions

Tags: performance, game, functional-programming, f#, chess

So I am trying to write, essentially from a blank slate, a program that plays [Grand Chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Chess). In short, it is a chess variant that is played with two extra pieces, on a 10x10 board, no castling, and optional promotion on the 8th and 9th ranks, mandatory on the last. Finally, you may not promote to a piece unless it has been captured (no 2 queens, for example.) Rest of the rules are the same as chess.

These functions will, hopefully, be the basis for both a UI to play the game and a simple engine to play against.

I have somewhat implemented the kind-of-complicated promotion rules, but I am not too sure about the implementation. It *should* only generate legal moves. The only legality check is checking whether the move ends with the King in check. I am maintaining that you can only promote to a captured piece by maintaining a piece list in the Position Type. this will probably generate tons of garbage, so any performance improvements are welcome.

**Edit**: The code below is a restructuring / renaming / refactoring of the original code posted here. I did so since there were no answers nor comments and I kept working on the code anyway. The algorithms used and the main logic are the same, however.

Without further ado:

## Types.fs

```
namespace Stamma

type Color = 
    | White
    | Black
    member x.Opp = 
        match x with
        | White -> Black
        | Black -> White

(*
This type is replaced by simple int * int tuples throughout

type Vector = 
    { Forward : int // changes per player 
      East : int } // to the Right of the white player. 
*)

type Piece = 
    | King
    | Queen
    | Marshal
    | Cardinal
    | Bishop
    | Knight
    | Rook
    | Pawn

type MoveType = 
    | Move
    | Capture
    | Promotion of Piece
    | CapAndPromotion of Piece

type Coordinates = 
    { Rank : int
      File : int }

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.UseNullAsTrueValue)>]
type Field = 
    | Empty
    | Piece of Piece * Color

type Position = 
    { Board : Map<Coordinates, Field>
      EnPassant : Coordinates
      Turn : Color
      KingWhite : Coordinates
      KingBlack : Coordinates
      CappedWhite : Piece list
      CappedBlack : Piece list 
      ReversibleCount : int}
```

## Piece.fs

```
[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Stamma.Piece

open System

let private charMap = 
    [ ('k', King)
      ('q', Queen)
      ('m', Marshal)
      ('c', Cardinal)
      ('p', Pawn)
      ('n', Knight)
      ('b', Bishop)
      ('r', Rook) ]
    |> Map.ofList

let ofChar c = 
    let color = 
        if Char.IsLower c then Black
        else White
    Piece(Map.find (Char.ToLower c) charMap, color)

let toChar color piece = 
    let ch = Map.findKey (fun c p -> p = piece) charMap
    if color = White then Char.ToUpper ch
    else ch

let internal vectors = 
    function 
    | Rook -> 
        [ (1, 0)
          (0, 1)
          (-1, 0)
          (0, -1) ]
    | Bishop -> 
        [ (1, 1)
          (-1, -1)
          (-1, 1)
          (1, -1) ]
    | King | Queen -> 
        [ (1, 0)
          (0, 1)
          (-1, 0)
          (0, -1)
          (1, 1)
          (-1, -1)
          (-1, 1)
          (1, -1) ]
    | Knight -> 
        [ (-2, -1)
          (-2, 1)
          (-1, -2)
          (-1, 2)
          (1, -2)
          (1, 2)
          (2, -1)
          (2, 1) ]
    | _ -> [] (* unused *)
```

## Board.fs

Everything from here onwards is on the assumption that

- First Rank is 1
- First File is 1
- Board is 10x10

The board is represented by a `Map<Coordinates, Field>` . Might later swap the coordinates type to be either represented as a `string` (such as `"a1"`) or an `int * int`, or just replace the whole thing with an `Array2D` or a bitboard (once I figure out how they work,) but I think optimizing the board representation can wait.

```
[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Stamma.Board

let private ofFenRank fenR = 
    let mutable baseArray = Array.create 10 Empty
    if fenR = "10" then baseArray
    else 
        let rec loop (rnk : string) count = 
            if count = 10 then ()
            elif System.Char.IsLetter rnk.[0] then 
                baseArray.[count] <- Piece.ofChar rnk.[0]
                loop (rnk.Substring 1) (count + 1)
            else 
                let dgt = int rnk.[0] - 48
                loop (rnk.Substring 1) (count + dgt)
        loop fenR 0
        baseArray

let ofFen (fen : string) = 
    fen.Split '/'
    |> Array.rev
    |> Array.map ofFenRank
    |> Array.collect id
    |> Array.mapi (fun idx F -> 
           ({ Rank = idx / 10 + 1
              File = idx % 10 + 1 }, F))
    |> Map.ofArray

(* logic translated from my C# experiment, which I probably stole from somewhere *)
let toFen board = 
    let mutable esc = 0
    let mutable sb = System.Text.StringBuilder()
    for r in 10..-1..1 do
        for f in 1..10 do
            match Map.find { Rank = r
                             File = f } board with
            | Empty -> esc <- esc + 1
            | Piece(p, c) -> 
                if esc > 0 then 
                    sb.Append esc |> ignore
                    esc <- 0
                else sb.Append(Piece.toChar c p) |> ignore
        if esc > 0 then 
            sb.Append esc |> ignore
            esc <- 0
        if r > 1 then sb.Append '/' |> ignore
    sb.ToString()

let empty = ofFen "10/10/10/10/10/10/10/10/10/10"
let start = 
    ofFen "r8r/1nbqkmcbn1/pppppppppp/10/10/10/10/PPPPPPPPPP/1NBQKMCBN1/R8R"

let toAscii board = 
    seq { 
        for r in 10..-1..1 do
            for f in 1..11 do
                if f = 11 then yield sprintf "| %d\n" r
                else 
                    match Map.find { Rank = r
                                     File = f } board with
                    | Empty -> yield "| "
                    | Piece(p, c) -> yield sprintf "|%c" (Piece.toChar c p)
        yield " a b c d e f g h i j\n"
    }
    |> String.concat ""
```

## Position.fs

```
[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Stamma.Position

(* Pawn Promotion logic *)

let private applyVector turn start (x, y) = 
    { Rank = 
          start.Rank + ((if turn = White then 1
                         else -1)
                        * x)
      File = start.File + y }

let private pawnMove start pos = 
    let reach = 
        match start.Rank, pos.Turn with
        | 3, White | 8, Black -> 2
        | _ -> 1

    let rec loop start acc r = 
        if r = 0 then acc
        else 
            let dist = applyVector pos.Turn start (1, 0)
            match Map.tryFind dist pos.Board with
            | Some Empty -> loop dist (dist :: acc) (r - 1)
            | _ -> acc

    loop start [] reach

let private pawnCap start pos = 
    [ -1; 1 ]
    |> List.map (fun x -> applyVector pos.Turn start (1, x))
    |> List.filter (fun sq -> 
           sq = pos.EnPassant || (match Map.tryFind sq pos.Board with
                                  | Some(Piece(_, c)) when c <> pos.Turn -> true
                                  | _ -> false))

let private promotionTarget start pos = 
    let proTarsWhite = 
        pos.CappedWhite
        |> List.distinct
        |> List.map Promotion

    let proTarsBlack = 
        pos.CappedBlack
        |> List.distinct
        |> List.map Promotion

    match pos.Turn, start.Rank with
    | White, n when n < 7 -> [ Move ]
    | Black, n when n > 4 -> [ Move ]
    | White, n when n < 9 -> Move :: proTarsWhite
    | Black, n when n > 2 -> Move :: proTarsBlack
    | White, _ -> proTarsWhite
    | _ -> proTarsBlack

(* Way finding Logic :
 * Result is ( Coordinates * Coordinates * MoveType )
 * Stands for ( Start Square * End Square * MoveType )
 *)

let private wayfindCore start pos piece reach = 
    let rec loop start acc reach vector = 
        if reach = 0 then acc
        else 
            let dist = applyVector pos.Turn start vector
            match Map.tryFind dist pos.Board with
            | Some(Piece(p, c)) when c <> pos.Turn -> (dist, Capture) :: acc
            | Some(Empty) -> loop dist ((dist, Move) :: acc) (reach - 1) vector
            | _ -> acc
    Piece.vectors piece
    |> List.collect (loop start [] reach)
    |> List.map (fun (d, m) -> start, d, m)

let rec private wayfindMoveAux start piece pos = 
    match piece with
    | Rook | Bishop | Queen -> wayfindCore start pos piece 10
    | Knight | King -> wayfindCore start pos piece 1
    | Marshal -> wayfindMoveAux start Rook pos @ wayfindMoveAux start Knight pos
    | Cardinal -> wayfindMoveAux start Bishop pos @ wayfindMoveAux start Knight pos
    | Pawn -> 
        pawnMove start pos 
        |> List.collect (fun x -> promotionTarget start pos |> List.map (fun y -> start, x, y))

let private wayfindCapsAux start piece pos = 
    match piece with
    | Pawn -> 
        pawnCap start pos
        |> List.collect (fun x -> promotionTarget start pos |> List.map (fun y -> start, x, y))
        |> List.map (fun (s, d, m) -> 
               (s, d, 
                match m with
                | Move | Capture -> Capture
                | Promotion(p) | CapAndPromotion(p) -> CapAndPromotion(p)))
    | _ -> 
        wayfindMoveAux start piece pos |> List.filter (function 
                                              | _, _, Capture | _, _, CapAndPromotion(_) -> true
                                              | _ -> false)

(* END OF AUX FUNCTIONS *)

(* START OF USEFUL FUNCTIONS *)

let wayfindMovesFrom start pos = 
    match Map.find start pos.Board with
    | Empty -> []
    | Piece(_, c) when c <> pos.Turn -> []
    | Piece(p, _) -> wayfindMoveAux start p pos

let wayfindCapsFrom start pos = 
    match Map.find start pos.Board with
    | Empty -> []
    | Piece(_, c) when c <> pos.Turn -> []
    | Piece(p, _) -> wayfindCapsAux start p pos

let wayfind pos = 
    pos.Board
    |> Map.toList
    |> List.collect (fun (s, f) -> 
           wayfindMovesFrom s pos @ (if f = Piece(Pawn, pos.Turn) then wayfindCapsFrom s pos
                                     else []))

(* Legality checking  *)
let isAttacked loc pos = 
    List.exists (fun (_, dist, _) -> 
        match Map.find dist pos.Board with
        | Piece(Rook, c) | Piece(Queen, c) | Piece(Marshal, c) when c = pos.Turn.Opp -> true
        | _ -> false) (wayfindCapsAux loc Rook pos) 
    && List.exists (fun (_, dist, _) -> 
           match Map.find dist pos.Board with
           | Piece(Knight, c) | Piece(Cardinal, c) | Piece(Marshal, c) when c = pos.Turn.Opp -> true
           | _ -> false) (wayfindCapsAux loc Knight pos) 
    && List.exists (fun (_, dist, _) -> 
           match Map.find dist pos.Board with
           | Piece(Bishop, c) | Piece(Queen, c) | Piece(Cardinal, c) when c = pos.Turn.Opp -> true
           | _ -> false) (wayfindCapsAux loc Bishop pos) 
    && List.exists (fun (_, dist, _) -> 
           match Map.find dist pos.Board with
           | Piece(Pawn, c) when c <> pos.Turn -> true
           | _ -> false) (wayfindCapsAux loc Pawn pos)
    && List.exists (fun (_, dist, _) -> 
           match Map.find dist pos.Board with
           | Piece(King, c) when c <> pos.Turn -> true
           | _ -> false) (wayfindCapsAux loc King pos)

let isDefended loc pos = isAttacked loc { pos with Turn = pos.Turn.Opp }

let isCheck pos = 
    if pos.Turn = White then isAttacked pos.KingWhite pos
    else isAttacked pos.KingBlack pos

let isLegal pos = 
    (* checks if the wrong king is in check *)
    isCheck { pos with Turn = pos.Turn.Opp } |> not

let applyMove pos (start, dist, move) = 
    let movingPiece = 
        match Map.find start pos.Board with
        | Piece(p, c) when c = pos.Turn -> p
        | _ -> failwith "What are you trying to move?"

    let endPiece, promo = 
        match move with
        | Promotion(p) | CapAndPromotion(p) -> p, true
        | _ -> movingPiece, false

    let capturedPiece = 
        match move with
        | Move | Promotion(_) -> None
        | _ -> 
            match Map.find dist pos.Board with
            | Piece(p, _) when p <> Pawn -> Some p
            | _ -> None

    let update capped turn = 
        match pos.Turn, capturedPiece with
        | t, Some p when t = turn -> p :: capped
        | _ -> capped

    let rec remove pred lst = 
        match lst with
        | h :: t when pred h -> t
        | h :: t -> h :: remove pred t
        | _ -> []

    let newBoard = 
        pos.Board
        |> Map.add dist (Piece(endPiece, pos.Turn))
        |> Map.add start Empty

    { pos with Board = 
                   if pos.EnPassant = dist && movingPiece = Pawn then 
                       newBoard |> Map.add { Rank = start.Rank
                                             File = dist.File } Empty
                   else newBoard
               KingWhite = 
                   if movingPiece = King && pos.Turn = White then dist
                   else pos.KingWhite
               KingBlack = 
                   if movingPiece = King && pos.Turn = Black then dist
                   else pos.KingBlack
               CappedWhite = update pos.CappedWhite Black |> remove (fun x -> promo && x = endPiece)
               CappedBlack = update pos.CappedBlack White |> remove (fun x -> promo && x = endPiece)
               Turn = pos.Turn.Opp
               EnPassant = 
                   if movingPiece = Pawn && abs (start.Rank - dist.Rank) = 2 then 
                       { Rank = (start.Rank + dist.Rank) / 2
                         File = start.File }
                   else 
                       { Rank = 0
                         File = 0 } }

let wayfindLegalPositions pos = 
    pos
    |> wayfind
    |> List.map (applyMove pos)
    |> List.filter isLegal

let isCheckmate pos = isCheck pos && (wayfindLegalPositions pos |> List.length) = 0
let isStalemate pos = not (isCheck pos) && (wayfindLegalPositions pos |> List.length) = 0
```

## Game.fs

```
[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Stamma.Game

open System

let start() = raise (NotImplementedException())

let makeMove game = raise (NotImplementedException())
```

Any improvements that could be suggested (especially performance or algorithm validity) are welcome. Of particular concern for me is where I can go forward from here? I realize I have the core logic, but how do I extend that core logic so I can play a game?

Answer (score 2):

In `toFen`, you don't need `sb` to be `mutable`. You're not *reassigning* it, but are instead *calling methods* on it, of which `mutable` does not affect.

The same thing applies to `baseArray` in `ofFenRank`. This doesn't need to be `mutable`, because you're not directly assigning to the array, but are assigning to elements in the array.

---

Generally, in F# it's preferred to `match` instead of `if`, especially with constants:

```
let private applyVector turn start (x, y) = 
    { Rank = 
          start.Rank + ((match turn with
                         | White -> 1
                         | _ -> -1)
                        * x)
      File = start.File + y }
```

Just as well:

```
let private wayfindCore start pos piece reach = 
    let rec loop start acc reach vector = 
        match reach with
        | 0 -> acc
        | _ -> let dist = applyVector pos.Turn start vector
               match Map.tryFind dist pos.Board with
               | Some(Piece(p, c)) when c <> pos.Turn -> (dist, Capture) :: acc
               | Some(Empty) -> loop dist ((dist, Move) :: acc) (reach - 1) vector
               | _ -> acc
    Piece.vectors piece
    |> List.collect (loop start [] reach)
    |> List.map (fun (d, m) -> start, d, m)
```

One more:

```
{ pos with Board = 
               match (pos.EnPassant, movingPiece) with
               | (ep, Pawn) when ep = dist ->
                   newBoard |> Map.add { Rank = start.Rank
                                         File = dist.File } Empty
               | _ -> newBoard
           KingWhite = 
               match (movingPiece, pos.Turn) with
               | (King, White) -> dist
               | _ -> pos.KingWhite
           KingBlack = 
               match (movingPiece, pos.Turn) with
               | (King, Black) -> dist
               | _ -> pos.KingBlack
           CappedWhite = update pos.CappedWhite Black |> remove (fun x -> promo && x = endPiece)
           CappedBlack = update pos.CappedBlack White |> remove (fun x -> promo && x = endPiece)
           Turn = pos.Turn.Opp
           EnPassant = 
               match (movingPiece, abs (start.Rank - dist.Rank)) with
               | (Pawn, 2) ->
                    { Rank = (start.Rank + dist.Rank) / 2
                      File = start.File }
               | _ ->
                    { Rank = 0
                      File = 0 } }
```

---

Other than that, there's not much I can say. I'm *not* an expert in F# by any means. You used tail-call recursion everywhere you could, which is good. You use `Option` and unions when appropriate, and you used functional paradigms everywhere. The only one I don't like is the `mutable esc`.

Rewriting `toFen` as follows *should* eliminate the need for this `mutable` variable, and follow functional paradigms as much as possible. (Reduced the number of `if` statements substantially.)

**Note**: I haven't yet tested this, you provided no test data, but it *should* provide the same result.

```
let toFen board = 
    let sb = System.Text.StringBuilder()
    let rec rLoop r acc =
        let rec fLoop f acc =
            let newAcc = 
                match Map.find { Rank = r
                                 File = f } board with
                | Empty -> acc + 1
                | Piece(p, c) -> 
                    match acc with
                    | v when v > 0 ->
                        sb.Append acc |> ignore
                        0
                    | _ ->
                        sb.Append(Piece.toChar c p) |> ignore
                        acc
            match f with
            | v when v < 10 -> fLoop (f + 1) newAcc
            | _ -> newAcc

        let newAcc = fLoop 1 acc
        let finalAcc =
            if newAcc > 0 then 
                sb.Append newAcc |> ignore
                0
            elif r > 1 then
                sb.Append '/' |> ignore
                newAcc
            else
                newAcc

        if r > 1 then
            rLoop (r - 1) newAcc
    rLoop 10 0
    sb.ToString()
```

Basically, we use recursive loops like the functional paradigms expect.

---

All-in-all this was a **very** well-written programme, I actually learned a lot from it and it forced me to think functionally for a moment, and helped me remove that `esc` mutable variable with a little effort. **Very good job!** :)

Comment: Nice answer.  I would add a couple of lines about the function of `ofFenRank`. Instead of (rnk.Substring 1) it is better to rewrite the function to pass current index